# python file handling

Tags: python, string, file

I'm working on Python 3.3 Windows.
I want to write a script that finds comma in a text file and shows the word between commas
Like

```
Denis, John, Blah ,Blah Blah
```

I want to know how can I take the value between commas and then match it with the one I give.
Ex: I give `John` and the program finds it in the file I want to be able also to find the word even if it's an reversed like `nohj` instead of `john`

Comment: What have you done ?, we are not here to do your work, show us what you have done and we'll help you. Also read this -> [How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have only opened the file,I'm trying to find the kommas in the file text.

Comment: not completely reverse I want to know if the word has specific letters in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def get_chars(string):
    l = []
    for c in string:
        if c not in l:
            l.append(c)
    return sorted(l)

with open('filename','r') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = [i.strip().lower() for i in data.split(',')]
search = input('Word to find: ').strip().lower()
for i in data[:]:
    if get_chars(i) == s_chars:
        print i
```

Comment: Thanks , worked like charm but how can I change the if i == search that it find the word when I give mixed letter.

Comment: @user2149541 Update!!! Look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
contents = open('textfile','r')
[re.search('John', p) for p in contents.read().split(',')]
contents.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split(",")` to split your string by commas. This yields a list. Then you can process it:

```
def process(s):
    if s.strip() == "John":
        print("Hi John")
        # do something interesting

data = open("/path/to/file.txt", "r").read()
map(process, data.split(","))
```